# How to view (debug) the database in Ionic2 app

Tags: database, sqlite, debugging, ionic2

How can I've got an app which uses SQLite database and Storage Native Component. It works fine but let's say I want to display it in form of tables (SELECT * FROM ...). Is there any way to do it? I tried Inspecting it using Chrome's DevTools under Application -> Storage and checked all the available options and everything is empty.

Comment: When using the ionic storage component. It decides which storage to use based on the device that is running the app. You can configure it: 
driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']
as found in : https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

When you are viewing on a desktop inside the browser, SQLite is not available so it should be using indexeddb or websql. This should be visible in the chrome debugger. If not then there is something going wrong storing the values. Providing code could help

Comment: @Juxture I've done it as mentioned in documentation and on device it works fine but I can't see it in the dev tools.

Comment: You can also try to deploy your app in physical device .. then try to Remote the device using ChromDevTool from there you can inspect what happen just make console log every process you want to see.

Comment: @JakeGarbo but that's what I'm doing. I'm running it on the real Android device with 4.2 and launching the ChromeDevTool where I can see all `console.log` and other stuff but database is empty. I can tell that it works fine because when I add something to the database and close the app it will  still be on the device.

Comment: It seems that when you run your code in the browser it will use IndexedDB or WebSQL and you will see it in the devtools. 

But when you emulate via the Android emulator or run your code on your device (in my case with cordova) you won't see anything in the browser even when you debug your app. The storage will be empty in this case. So My code works but as the initial question I have no clue where to find it in Android